# Finding and removing specific elements using css classes

Tags: jquery

I'm far from a JavaScript expert but I'm trying to migrate some mootools code to jQuery but am struggling!

I have a web form which contains several tables with a css class of '.table-row'. Upon clicking a button, I'd like to find all the rows which have '.table-row' and if their display property is set to none, I'd like to remove them from the page before submitting.

This is my mootools code:

```
function remove_hidden_elements() {
    var myElements = $$('.table-row');
    myElements.each(function (item, index) {
        var vis = item.getStyle('display');
        if (vis == 'none') {
            item.dispose();
        }
    });
}
```

Please can someone point me in the right direction for achieving this within jQuery?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide an HTML snippet you are working with? It's unclear whether the rows or the tables have that .table-row class

Comment: So far it doesn't look like you have read the basic documentation at [the jquery website](http://jquery.com). Start with the "How Jquery Works" article and the "Getting Started" tutorial. That will answer a lot of your questions.

Comment: @spliter - it's the rows that have the class. Sorry, I should have been more explicit in my post.

Comment: @Cos Callis - You're right, I should definitely read through again and get a thorough understanding. I have read some documentation but I was struggling quite a bit so thought I'd ask.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who replied. It's very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery and MooTools aren't really all that far apart; jQuery is more set-oriented and MooTools more element-orientated, but other than that...

The literal jQuery equivalent is:

```
function remove_hidden_elements() {
    var myElements = $('.table-row');
    myElements.each(function() {
        if (this.style.display === 'none') {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
}
```

Basically, swapping `$$()` for [`$()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) (aka `jQuery()`) and using the raw DOM element that jQuery will pass into its version of [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to check the `style.display` property, and then using [`remove`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) (which will also find and destroy any event handlers or other associated data, provided they were hooked up / associated via jQuery).

Somewhat more idiomatic jQuery might be:

```
function remove_hidden_elements() {
    var myElements = $('.table-row');
    myElements.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.is(":not(:visible)")) {
            $this.remove();
        }
    });
}
```

Or even eliminating the variable:

```
function remove_hidden_elements() {
    $('.table-row').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.is(":not(:visible)")) {
            $this.remove();
        }
    });
}
```

jQuery's [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector handles several cases other than the literal `style.display == 'none'`, and [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) inverts it. (Or *rather more directly*, use [`:hidden`](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) as [3nigma points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656980/finding-and-removing-specific-elements-using-css-classes/6657018#6657018) — I must be tired.) But if you specifically want to handle just that case of `style.display == 'none'` (and there's nothing wrong with that, it can be more efficient), use the first example above (with or without the `myElements` variable).

Comment: Do you mean `if ($this.not(':visible'))` ? You're removing only the visible elements at the moment...

Comment: @Beejamin: Thank you, yes, I *had* inverted that logic, hadn't I?

Comment: Many thanks, T.J. This is exactly what I was looking for. Works a treat.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the [`:hidden`](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) selector

```
$(".table-row:hidden").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use :not and :visible selectors to filter the rows.

Try this:

```
function remove_hidden_elements() {
  $('.table-row:not(:visible)').remove();
}
```

**Note:**

As per jQuery docs

```
Elements can be considered hidden for several reasons:

•They have a CSS display value of none.  

•They are form elements with type="hidden".  

•Their width and height are explicitly set to 0.  

•An ancestor element is hidden, so the element is not shown on the page.
```

If you are strictly looking for disaply:none filter then try:

```
function remove_hidden_elements() {
  $('.table-row').filter(function(){
    return (this.style.display === "none");
  }).remove();
}
```